# error in static storage class in structure initialization

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

'C' seem to permit initialization of members of a structure inside a function as long as the storage class of the structure is not 'static', Trying to do so returns following compilation error:

> error: initializer element is not constant

Code snip

```
typedef struct data {
    int age;
    char *name;
} data_t;

void foo(data_t student)
{
    //data_t s1 = student; <--- works
    static data_t s1 = student; <--- throws error
    printf("%s: s1.age: %d, s1.name: %s\n",__FUNCTION__,s1.age, s1.name);
}
```

Appreciate, if you throw some insight.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why you want `static` and do you know what does it mean in this  case?

Comment: I was aware that the variables which are declared as 'static' will be stored in the data segment and hence, they will retain their value across context switches, but I wasn't aware of the fact that "Objects with static storage has to be initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions in C.", which @meyumer pointed out below. I was trying this to confirm what I read somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Objects with static storage has to be initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions in C. You are trying to initialize the static declared object `s1` by a non static object `student`. That is why the compiler throws the error `initializer element is not constant`.